# Renaming a NavigationFolder in Outlook 2016 using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

What I want to do is:

1. Create a new calendar group
2. Get a shared calendar and put into 1.
3. Rename the shared calendar

And the code is:

```
Dim outlookObj As Outlook.Application
Dim namespaceObj As NameSpace
Dim recipientObj As Outlook.recipient
Dim paneObj As Outlook.NavigationPane
Dim moduleObj As Outlook.CalendarModule
Dim navGroupObj As Outlook.NavigationGroup
Dim navFolderObj As Outlook.NavigationFolder
Dim folderObj As Folder

'Create a recipient "John Smith"
Set outlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set namespaceObj = outlookObj.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set recipientObj = namespaceObj.CreateRecipient("John Smith")

'Create a new calendar group
Set paneObj = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane
Set moduleObj = paneObj.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)
Set navGroupObj = moduleObj.NavigationGroups.Create("NewCalendarGroup")

If(recipientObj.Resolved) Then
    'Add a shared calendar into "NewCalendarGroup"
    Set folderObj = namespaceObj.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipientObj, olFolderCalendar)
    Set navFolderObj = navGroupObj.NavigationFolders.Add(folderObj)

    'Rename the shared calendar
    navFolderObj.DisplayName = "John's calendar"  'error
End If
```

However, since [NavigationFolder.DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/navigationfolder-displayname-property-outlook) is read-only, Outlook shows error on this line:

```
'Rename the shared calendar
navFolderObj.DisplayName = "John's calendar"  'error
```

I can right click the calendar and rename it on the screen, but how can I do the same thing using VBA? Is there any way to change the DisplayName which is read-only?

Comment: One day, many years from now we may have an answer.  Or not.